# Newton's Method Reversed (using iteration formula to figure out f(x))

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-series

The iteration formula $x_{n+1} = x_n − \cos(x_n)\sin(x_n) + R\cos^2x_n$ , where $R$ is a positive constant, was obtained by applying Newton's method to some function $f(x)$. What was $f(x)$? What can this formula be used for?

So $f(x)/f'(x) = −\cos(x_n)\sin(x_n) + R\cos^2x_n$...but I tried out different equations and have no idea what to do from this point.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see... your first mistake is already evident: the equation of the tangent line through $(x_n,f(x_n))$ is
$$\frac{y-f(x_n)}{x-x_n}=f^{\prime}(x_n)$$
Setting $y_{n+1}=y=0$ and solving for $x_{n+1}=x$, we get
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f^{\prime}(x_n)}$$
That means our starting point should be
$$\frac{f(x)}{f^{\prime}(x)}=\cos x\sin x-R\cos^2x$$
So you have a wrong sign and inconsistent notation ($x$ vs. $x_n$) in your question.

To solve, take reciprocals to get
$$\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{f(x)}=\frac d{dx}\ln f(x)=\frac1{(\sin x-R\cos x)\cos x}$$
Integrating both sides via the substitution $z=\tan\frac x2$, so $\cos x=\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}$, $\sin x=\frac{2z}{1+z^2}$, and $dx=\frac{2dz}{1+z^2}$ and partial fractions decomposition, we get
$$\begin{align}\ln\left|f(x)\right|&=\int\frac{dx}{(\sin x-R\cos x)\cos x}=\int\frac{2(1+z^2)dz}{(1-z^2)(Rz^2+2z-R)}\\
&=\int\left(\frac{2z}{1-z^2}+\frac{2Rz+2}{Rz^2+2z-R}\right)dz\\
&=-\ln\left|1-z^2\right|+\ln\left|Rz^2+2z-R\right|+C_1\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{Rz^2+2z-R}{1-z^2}\right|+C_1\\
&=\ln\left|\frac{2z}{1+z^2}\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2}-R\right|+C_1\\
&=\ln\left|\tan x-R\right|+C_1\end{align}$$
So
$$f(x)=\pm e^{C_1}\left(\tan x-R\right)=C\left(\tan x-R\right)$$
Which may be checked by differentiation. This formula may be used to find $x=\tan^{-1}R$

Comment: wow the lnf(x) step is genius thank you

Answer (score 0):

Newton's Method is 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
so if the former iteration formula is 
$$x_{n+1} = x_n − \cos(x_n)\sin(x_n) + R\cos^2x_n$$
then the corresponding $f(x)/f'(x) = \cos(x_n)\sin(x_n) - R\cos^2x_n$
and the next step is to solve this ordinary differential equation, but it is too hard for ordinary people like me (maybe include u:), i use one python package named sympy to help me solve. The answer is as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{-C_1\cdot\tan(x)}2, &\text{for $R$=0}\\[10pt]
\frac{C1 \cdot R \cdot \tan^2(\frac{x}2) - C_1 \cdot R + 2 \cdot C_1 \cdot \tan(\frac{x}2)}{R \cdot \tan^2(\frac{x}2)-R}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I hope I made it clear, Please feed me back if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your second formula simplifies : $C_1-\frac{C_1}R \tan(x)$

Comment: oh did NOT think of that! ODE was actually a pre-requisite for this but do I use laplace or some other method? thanks for reminding me but I do not rmb much about ODE anymore